# Debugging a WPF application with PIX / Visual Studio 11

Tags: wpf, directx, visual-studio-2012, directx-11, pix

i´m just working on a WPF application which uses DirectX 11 to render contents.
Now the problem is, that i´m not able to debug DirectX.

If i´m using PIX, i always get an Error: 0x00000007b, that the application was unable to start (after clicking "Run Experiment").

If i´m using Visual Studio 11 and press "Capture Frame", then it runs the progressbar infinite long and after pressing "Stop Debugging" it still shows the progress bar and now the message "This application uses a incompatible DirectX version or unsupported features. The playback may is incomplete".

Why is this so? Why could my application be unsupported? Is this because of WPF?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know - but I've got exactly the same error and posted a question over at SharpDX forums - so far no answer. Anyone? 
http://sharpdx.org/forum/4-general/302-graphics-debugging-in-vs-2012-rc#1572

Comment: I recently added a issue on MS Connect. After a few days I got their answer: This issue will be scheduled, because the WPF Team is currently working on features which most developers need / want. It´s obviously to minor for them to be fixed in the near future :-(